# How to download files through a custom action in Rails Admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-admin

How can I download a file through a custom action in Rails Admin. As the file which I'm sending is ZIP format but after getting downloaded its a nested zip which on opening creates another zip file and just goes on.

So basically this is my custom action where I'm calling my Service which will create a zip file through `gem rubyzip` and I'm sending the file_path of the created zip file with is on my local machine(e.g file_path as "#{Rails.root}/abc.zip")

```
        else
          # all your code that does the work
          import_params = params.require(:documents)
                                .permit(:email)

          if import_params[:email].present?
            @result = Download::Forms.call(mail_id: import_params[:email])
            if @result[:status]
              flash.now[:notice] = 'File Downloaded'
              send_file(
                    @result[:file_path],
                    filename: @result[:file_name],
                    type: "application/zip"
              )
            else
              flash.now[:error] = "Failed to Download because #{@result[:error_message]}"
            end
          else
            flash.now[:notice] = 'Please Enter Email Address'
          end
          @result
        end
```

As I also send the `@result` in the end so that I can also try `link_to` method to download the file but all in vain. I'm using **Rails 4.2.6**

Some more information regarding the **file types** is that I tried a txt file and  a pdf file also to check whether they are downloading properly but the same result they got downloaded but they were not proper as txt file was containing nothing and pdf can't be opened.

The files are getting downloaded with my **custom action** name and not from the file name which is the right naming if I download a file from any simple action.

Any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: if you download the original zip to your system, you can run `unzip <path>` with a shell subcommand to extract it.

Comment: I tried doing so but the following error came
`End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not
  a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the
  latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on
  the last disk(s) of this archive.`
and when I used this command to the zip file created in my Rails.root it worked fine extracted the files perfectly